# How to create a calculated field in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'd like to create a bar chart where each bar's height is determined by a calculated field and each bar represents a certain month.

The formula for the calculated field is the aggregate of the 'amount' field but is filtered based on the following criteria for each bar.

The data is filtered for all items that have a date less than the last day of the month.

Currently, I've tried the following:

- After creating a calculated field, I've entered the following text: SUM([Account MRR])

However I'm unsure how to have the calculated field reference the last day of the month in the column.

Comment: Do I understand it right: You would like to add up all `Amount` values if the date is NOT the last day of the month? i.e you add values for 21/12, 26/12 and 30/12 but not the ones from the 31/12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your Date field in the filters shelf. Then choose the date you want..